# Check if a panel page is enabled programmatically?

Tags: 7, panels, chaos-tool-suite

I need to be able to verify if a panel page (which is just a variant of a ctools page) is enabled or disabled.  How would one do this, programmatically?  If it is disabled, how would one enable it, programmatically?

Comment: I think that thread is exactly what you are looking for: https://www.drupal.org/node/1837948

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[`panels_load_display`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!panels!panels.module/function/panels_load_display/7)

Then check the `disabled` flag for page status.

Comment: How do you get the display id?